# Twilio Studio Flow - Flow execution stuck due to flow not transitioning

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

Twilio Studio Flow is having a problem with transitioning to the next widget when a user disconnects the phone. This causes the phone number used to not receive further calls as Twilio keeps the execution alive with that phone number. This is causing massive issues!

To explain the scenario/problem - When Twilio successfully calls the user and the user answers to start going through the flow, the user disconnects the call towards the end of the flow, after the hangup event is triggered on the widget, the flow manages to move through a couple of widgets after this, however stops on a widget which causes the execution to get stuck as the call is not being disconnected I assume. The widget it get's stuck on is a Say/Play and has an autocomplete which should move to the hangup function.

Here are some images to help with my explanation...

Image of the logs:
[image]

Image of the widget which the call is stuck on:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best approach for this is to open a support ticket for them to investigate further. Twilio does have a programmatic way of ending an execution here but ideally it wouldn’t be in a stuck state to begin with.

[Update an Execution](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution#update-an-execution)

[Understanding and Avoiding Stuck Executions in Twilio Studio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019383714-Understanding-and-Avoiding-Stuck-Executions-in-Twilio-Studio)